# Replicate directory structure applying a command to each file instead of simply copying it?

Tags: xargs, conversion, filter

Over time, I've encountered the same pattern again and again: I have some kind of directory structure:

```
example/
├── a
│   └── c
│       ├── d.txt (120k)
│       └── e.txt (60k)
└── b
    └── f.txt (280k)
```

And I want to "copy" the files over to another directory, say, `example_grepped`, applying a command to each as if in place of `cp` - say, `grep ERROR` so that say, I end up with a folder with the same structure but with files filtered through the `grep`.

```
example_grepped/
├── a
│   └── c
│       ├── d.txt (1k)
│       └── e.txt (0b)
└── b
    └── f.txt (12k)
```

Same pattern for converting media files (FLACs to MP3s, PNGs to JPGs), and this time when converting different schema formats as part of a build process.

Is there a generic command that I could use? Something like `foobar example example_grepped --command 'grep ERROR'` or `foobar flacs mp3s --command 'ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3'`?

An obscure `xargs` flag perhaps? (a `find` piped through `xargs` would *almost* suffice, but most if not all commands expect the directory structure to already exist.)

Comment: To duplicate the directory structure you could use `find` with `cpio`. `cd /path/to/example && find . -type d|cpio -pdv /path/to/example_grepped`. (Omit `-v` if you don't want the directories to be listed while processing.) After this you can use `find` with `xargs` as proposed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Closest answer I can find without separately recreating the directory structure is to use [install](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install):

```
cd example
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'grep ERROR {} | install -D /dev/stdin /tmp/example_grepped/{}' \;
```

Unfortunately the above can only work if your command can throw its result to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

filter() {

    local target_root="${@: -1}"

    target_path=$(sed -E "s/[^/]*/$target_root/" <<< "$1")
    target_dir=$(dirname "$target_path")

    mkdir -p "$target_dir"

    if [[ -f $1 ]]; then
        # do your grep thing here
        grep burger "$1" > "$target_path"
    fi
}

export -f filter
source_root="example"
target_root="example_grepped"

find "$source_root/" -print0 | xargs -0 -I content bash -c "filter 'content' '$target_root'"
```

This script also works with directory and file names that contain spaces.

Run this script where the source directory ("example") is located.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to use a program that does recursive copies anyway. I checked `rsync`, but could not find a callback option on a quick glance. But gnu `tar` has an option `--to-command` for which you can provide a command to be run that gets the file's input into `stdin`. But how to get the file created then? Well, the command called finds the current file name in `$TAR_FILENAME`.

Putting it all together, the basic call is

```
tar cf - example | tar xf - --to-command="./script example_grepped 'grep-pattern'"
```

where script could be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p $(dirname "$1/$TAR_FILENAME")
grep '$2' >"$1/$TAR_FILENAME"
exit 0
```

Another way to approach this, would be to wrap the tar pipe in a script that gets the command to run on the command line. Yet the escaping for the `mkdir ...dirname` construct will be a bit challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel you can do something like this:

```
cd src
find . -type f | parallel 'mkdir -p ../dst/{//}; dostuff --input {} --output ../dst/{}'
```